# Sending to multiple reciepients powershell

Tags: html, powershell

i use the script below to send emails from a powershell script.

```
$smtpServer = "mail.company.com"
$smtpFrom = "Check <check@company.com>"
$smtpTo = "user1@company.com"
$messageSubject = "Daily Check from $thedate"

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true

$message.Body = $Body | ConvertTo-HTML -head $style -body $Body

$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
$smtp.Send($message)
```

It works fine untill i add more reciepients like this...

```
$smtpTo = "user1@company.com", "user2@company.com"
```

I also tried putting it inside an array like this....

```
$smtpTo = @("user1@company.com", "user2@company.com")
```

None of them work for me. Hope someone can help

Comment: maybe "user1@company.com; user2@company.com" is doing the trick?

Comment: Nope, i keep getting ""The specified string is not in the form required for an e-mail"

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241816/powershell-send-mailmessage-email-to-multiple-recipients

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.To` property of System.Mail.MailMessage [is a collection that you can add emails to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddresscollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
$Message.to.add('myotheremail@mydomain.net')
$message.Subject = $messageSubject
$message.IsBodyHTML = $true
```