# PowerShell ConvertFrom-CSV horizontally

Tags: powershell, csv

This might sound like a stupid question, but I would like to know how to import some mail addresses into PowerShell to send one mail to all of them like `Send-MailMessage -To $MailTo`.

I already managed to remove the text `MailTo:` in the beginning of the line. The example will make it more clear:

**Input file:**

```
# Comment
MailTo: User1@domain.com, User2@domain.com, User3@domain.com
MailTo: User4@domain.com, User5@domain.com, User6@domain.com, User7@domain.com, User8@domain.com
```

**The code:**

```
$File = (Get-Content -Path $ImportFile) -notlike  '#*' | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Where {$_ -ne ""}
$MailTo = $File | where { $_ -like "MailTo:*" } | Foreach {$_ -replace "^MailTo: "}
```

**Solution:**

```
$MailTo = ($File | where { $_ -like "MailTo:*" } | Foreach {$_ -replace "^MailTo: "}) -split ',\s*' | Foreach {$_.Trim()} | Where {$_}
```

Thanks to Joey below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you essentially just want all mail addresses from that file? Or just from a particular line?

In the former case something like

```
$addresses = ((Get-Content $ImportFile) -replace '#.*|^MailTo:\s+') -split ',\s*'
```

should suffice. You can pass that array to the `-To` parameter of `Send-MailMesssage`. Perhaps there is still some stray whitespace in there afterwards, but that can easily be solved by piping the above to `| %{$_.Trim()}`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. But it doesn't work.. When I try `Send-MailMessage` to an array, only the last user receives the message, not everyone.

Comment: That's not what the documentation states, but assuming that it is indeed broken, that's trivial to work around. Just send one mail to each address, instead of one mail to all of them.

Comment: I actually need it to be one e-mail to multiple recipients. Same problem stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241816/powershell-send-mailmessage-email-to-multiple-recipients). I maybe need to build a `[String]` like `'User1@domain.com', 'User2@domain.com', ..`.

Comment: The author of that question explicitly converted the recipient array to string and passed that. I still doubt that sending a mail to multiple recipients does not work.

Comment: You're right, it does work when I manually fill it like `$addresses="User1@domain.com","User2@domain.com"`. But your proposal has a blank line as first line in there which might cause the issue.

Comment: Then add another `|?{$_}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61828/discussion-between-darklite1-and-joey).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this variant, more robust:

```
$data = cat file
[regex] $re = "(?:\G(?!\A)|^MailTo:[ ]*)(?:[ ]*,[ ]*)?(?'mail'[^,\s]+)"
$address = $data | 
  select-string $re -all | 
       foreach {$_.matches}|foreach {$_.groups['mail'].value}
Write-output $address
```

For example if your $data contains:

```
# comment foo@bar.com, boo@domain.com
Mailto: mail@d.com, mail2@.col.col ...etc
Mailto: mailto@do.com 
Dummy@mail.com, mail3@goo.com
Data other data
```

It return exact data

Comment: Thank you walid, but what is the advantage of this regex in comparison to the other?

Comment: Thank you for the extra feedback Walid. The `Comment` section is already filtered out within the variale `$File`. So that's not something I worry about. I tested both solutions, the one in my OP and yours and they provide the same result. So both are ok I guess :)