# Send mail via gmail with PowerShell V4

Tags: security, powershell, gmail, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

I have been using this PowerShell script to send my an email to me when opened.

```
$EmailFrom = "notifications@somedomain.com"
$EmailTo = "anything@gmail.com" 
$Subject = "sample subject" 
$Body = "sample body" 
$SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" 
$SMTPClient = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer, 587) 
$SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
$SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("YOURUSERNAME", "YOURPASSWORD"); 
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
```

I changed the $EmailTo to my email address, and the YOURUSERNAME / YOURPASSWORD to my correct login information.

I know as a fact that this was working last month. I recently changed my Gmail password, and obviously this script stopped working. However, I changed the YOURPASSWORD to the correct new one, and now for some reason I am getting an error when opening:

```
$SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
Exception calling "Send" with "4" argument(s): "The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not 
authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"
At line:9 char:1
+ $SMTPClient.Send($EmailFrom, $EmailTo, $Subject, $Body)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException
```

I am on Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit, and I believe I was on PowerShell V2, but today updated to V4 due to me thinking that might have been the issue.

I have also turned on unsecured apps in my Gmail setting since someone said that might be the issue. It was not, and to this day, I am still getting the error.

Do you know if it is still possible to send Gmails through PowerShell? Or am I just missing something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Apart from the obvious (double-check your username/password), have you tried using the `Send-MailMessage` cmdlet instead?

Comment: Not really. Do you have a script using it that currently works? :D

Comment: `Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -UseSsl -SmtpServer $SmtpServer -Port 587 -Credential (Get-Credential)` - input username and password in the credential prompt

Comment: Thank you, but what I need is for it to be completely automatic. Like where it will input the credentials by it self like the script I had. You know what I mean? :D

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but Gmail send me a mail with a link for "Less secure app", I put it on ON then it worked. Here the link just change USERNAME with your username for google.

```
https://accounts.google.com/AccountChooser?Email=USERNAME@gmail.com&continue=https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps?rfn%3D27%26rfnc%3D1%26eid%3D3301110864727181130%26et%3D0%26asae%3D2
```

Comment: How did you managed to have Gmail send you that link? You should add those steps to your answer, as it will greatly help users with similar questions (besides, I have my doubts that your specific link will work for other users. I would guess Gmail generates a new link for every less secure app that requests it, so the correct answer in that case would be the steps you should add)