# email sender powershell script

Tags: powershell, networking

i am trying to make a simple powershell mail sender script , but i keep getting an exception in the "Send-MailMessage " command , but i don't quite understand why .

this is the script :    `$Sender = "powershell121@gmail.com" $Reciever = "powershell122@gmail.com" $Subject = "testing script" $Body = " this is a mail sender powershell script , from me to me  " $SMTPServer = "smtp.gmail.com" $SMTPPort = "587" Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -to $Reciever -Subject $Subject`
-Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -port $SMTPPort -UseSsl  `-Credential (Get-Credential)`
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- the exception i'm getting :

```
`      Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server
response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at
At line:7 char:1
+ Send-MailMessage -From $Sender -to $Reciever -Subject $Subject `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient:SmtpClient) [Send-MailMessage], SmtpExcept
   ion
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SmtpException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1252335/send-mail-via-gmail-with-powershell-v2s-send-mailmessage

Comment: Based off the error message, seems like you entered the wrong credentials.

Comment: @Toni that's great , i wasn't aware of the adjustments i would have to make before using my gmail to send the message , thanks ♥

Comment: @AbrahamZinala the credentials are right but my email security configurations was restricted so powershell couldn't access it to send the mail , appreciate the help ♥